# pcm input on mp3 encoder

Tags: mp3, codec, pcm, wave, encoder

does anyone know how a PCM input is partitioned in a mp3 encoder? I already know that each input is a small part of the original wave and inside the encoder it's divided in 32 smaller parts and so forth, but what is the size of this initial input?

Comment: In a mp3 encoder, the input will be a small part of the total sound, one at a time. what is the size of this input? I'm talking about the PCM in this image -> http://db.tt/s4dnK0Nt <- in this case, why it's 768Kbps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other perceptual audio codecs, mp3 processes sound in chunks. mp3 chunk size is 1152 samples. If sampling frequency is 44100 Hz than this is close to 20 miliseconds, which is resolution of human hearing system.

Good place for this kind of questions is [Hydrogen Audio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showforum=55).